# How to delete rows from a CSV file when I just know the row number?

Tags: python, csv, row, delete-row

I am a beginner and currently writing a code in python where if the CSV's length gets more than a given number, the first row will be deleted, making space for more.
Is there a function that can delete rows in a CSV just by row number?

Comment: Hello there, can you show your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no special function for that since that can be done with a simple `for` loop.

Here we have an input file which is read line by line while skipping the lines with the row number contained in `rownumbers_to_remove`.
Notice the `enumerate(...)` with the `start=1` parameter to make the index start at `1` instead of `0`. This might improve readability a bit.

```py
lines = list()
rownumbers_to_remove= [5,6]

with open('name-of-file.csv', 'r') as read_file:
    reader = csv.reader(read_file)
    for row_number, row in enumerate(reader, start=1):
        if(row_number not in rownumbers_to_remove):
            lines.append(row)

with open('name-of-file.csv', 'w') as write_file:
    writer = csv.writer(write_file)
    writer.writerows(lines)
```